# Issue with upgraded Boost on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: c++, boost, ros

I have a code base with CMake. Initially I had Boost 1.48. Today upgraded Boost to the latest version (ie. 1.59). I have ubuntu 12.04.

I had a code base that used boost::thread.
Now it is giving following error :

```
Linking CXX executable /home/eeuser/ros_workspaces/HeloRosProject/devel/lib/visensor_node/visensor_node
/home/eeuser/ros_workspaces/HeloRosProject/devel/lib/libvisensor.so: error: undefined reference to 'boost::thread::join_noexcept()'
/home/eeuser/ros_workspaces/HeloRosProject/devel/lib/libvisensor.so: error: undefined reference to 'boost::thread::start_thread_noexcept()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/eeuser/ros_workspaces/HeloRosProject/devel/lib/visensor_node/visensor_node] Error 1
make[1]: *** [visensor_node/CMakeFiles/visensor_node.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

Here is how my cmakefile looks like

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(visensor_node)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp 
  message_generation
  geometry_msgs
  sensor_msgs 
  cv_bridge 
  std_msgs 
  image_transport 
  camera_info_manager 
  dynamic_reconfigure
  cmake_modules
)

# check libvisensor version, flags not used later
find_package(libvisensor 1.1.0 REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system thread date_time)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)  
add_message_files(
  DIRECTORY msg
  FILES visensor_imu.msg 
  visensor_time_host.msg
  visensor_calibration.msg
)

add_service_files(
    FILES
    visensor_calibration_service.srv
)

generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES geometry_msgs)

include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${libvisensor_INCLUDE_DIRS})

find_package(Eigen REQUIRED)
include_directories(${EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR})
add_definitions(${EIGEN_DEFINITIONS})

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED COMPONENTS core highgui imgproc)

generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(cfg/visensor_node.cfg)

if(NOT DEFINED CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
endif(NOT DEFINED CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -march=native -Wall -std=c++0x -D__STRICT_ANSI__")

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  CATKIN_DEPENDS
  roscpp 
  sensor_msgs 
  cv_bridge 
  std_msgs 
  image_transport 
  camera_info_manager 
)

#build and add libvisensor system library dependency
add_executable(visensor_node src/visensor_node.cpp src/visensor.cpp )

add_dependencies(visensor_node ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS}})
target_link_libraries(visensor_node ${libvisensor_LIBRARIES} ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_THREAD_LIBRARY} )
```

Driving me crazy with this error...!
Please help.

Comment: Are you using ros hydro?

Comment: Your version of ROS is probably not compatible with the newer Boost. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33231855/2095383).

Answer (score 0):

In all likelihood you're not linking to the Boost Thread binary (libboost_thread.so) that matches the version of the headers used when compiling.

Perhaps you can make CMake tell you the exact include directories and library directories involved.

If they look ok (e.g. `-I /my/boost/path/boost` and `-L /my/boost/path/stage/libs`) then you must have forgotten to build the 1.59 version of the libraries.